# Run function on vector without sapply

Tags: r, function, vector

I would like to understand how I can write a function to execute a certain rule on the elements of a vector.
Assume I want to multiply by a value all the elements of a vector, the below code returns:

```
a<-c(1, 3, 5, 7, 10)
f <-function(x){
f<-c()
for (i in x)  
  {temp=i*sqrt(2)
   print(temp) # not necessary, just to view the intermediate numbers
   f[i]<-temp
   }
f
} 
out<-f(a); out
   # [1]  1.414214        NA  4.242641        NA  7.071068        NA  9.899495        NA        NA 14.142136
```

So it returns NA to the values corresponding to position 2, 4, etc - which are not in my vector a.
I know I could simply run one of the following, but I would like to understand how I can achieve the same result by building a function.

```
  a*sqrt(2)
  sapply(a, FUN = function(x)x*sqrt(2))
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can also do something like `f1 <- function(vec, n){vec*sqrt(n)}` and try it for different root sizes, `f1(a, 2)` or `f1(a, 3)` and so on...- However, you need to be more explicit on what you want as an outcome as there is a bit of confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function only has to work on vectors with unique values, you could simply replace the `[i]` index with `match(i, x)`:

```
a<-c(1, 3, 5, 7, 10)
f <-function(x){
f<-c()
for (i in x)  
  {temp=i*sqrt(2)
   print(temp) # not necessary, just to view the intermediate numbers
   f[match(i, x)]<-temp
   }
f
} 
out<-f(a); out

> out
[1]  1.414214  4.242641  7.071068  9.899495 14.142136
```

Comment: However, the NAs are Missing

Comment: @loki I think NAs are supposed to be missing

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your reply. Yes I wanted the NAs to be removed, so the answer is the right one. @LAP, could you please kindly confirm what the match function does in this context?

Comment: Do you have a specific case where you want to apply this kind of function? It seems rather suboptimal compared to using `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

### with `NA` values vectorized:

```
x <- 1:max(a)
roots <- x * sqrt(2)
roots[!(x %in% a)] <- NA
roots
# [1]  1.414214        NA  4.242641        NA  7.071068        NA  9.899495        NA        NA 14.142136
```

A solution which is vectorized:
First, we create a sequence of integers and take their square root. Afterwards, all the values not in a will be replaced with `NA`

### Vectorize a previously defined function:

By using vectors in `R` you could also run the function without using `sapply`. The function will be automatically applied to each element of the vector like this:

```
f <- function(x){
  x * sqrt(2)
}

f(a)
# [1]  1.414214  4.242641  7.071068  9.899495 14.142136
```

Comment: FYI, OP states: *"how I can achieve the same result by building a function"*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However as Sotos mentioned my question is around how I can achieve the same result with a function (i.e. amending the function I already wrote) . Thanks

Comment: I added a solution and small explanation using a function.